# ngClass with three different states

Tags: angular, ng-class

I have no idea if this is the dumbest way to do this, but you have to start at some point, and this seemed like one way to go.

Anyways, I have created a `div` box. This box appears when a button is clicked, i.e. this click adds a class to the box. When the box appears it has two buttons - both which does something to the box.

Each button has these two functions:

```
States: Array<boolean> = new Array;

toggleState(firstIndex: number, secondIndex: number): void {
    let totalIndex = this.getTotalIndex(firstIndex, secondIndex);

    this.States[totalIndex] = !this.States[totalIndex];
}

getState(firstIndex: number, secondIndex: number): boolean {
    let totalIndex = this.getTotalIndex (firstIndex, secondIndex);

    return this.States[totalIndex];
}
```

This is just a way for me to get the state for each individual item/ID, where this box can appear. But again, I then have two other buttons with similar functions (only the name differs).

The buttons are then activated by:

```
<a (click)="toggleState1(firstIndex, secondIndex)">Button 1</a>
<a (click)="toggleState2(firstIndex, secondIndex)">Button 2</a>
<a (click)="toggleState3(firstIndex, secondIndex)">Button 3</a>
```

Now, the trouble I am having (which I can't get to work, and it also looks terrible tbh) is with the `div` box HTML, which currently looks like:

```
<div [ngClass]="getState1(firstIndex, secondIndex) ? getState2(firstIndex, secondIndex) ? getState3(firstIndex, secondIndex) ?
    'box-regular appear transparent' :  // here the box has appeared, and is transparent
    'box-regular' :                     // here the box has not yet appeared
    'box-regular appear enlarge' :      // here the box has appeared, and enlarged
    'box-regular appear'" >             // here the box has appeared
```

Now, when I run this, I can't seem to get all the buttons working. It's only two out of three that actually works. There is always one, no matter how I arrange it, that doesn't work.

So basically, what am I doing wrong here ? :)

Comment: The syntax is not correct in your ngClass, you are using condition ? true : false,
Instead of true and false you use more conditions and it is not readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you always used box-regular then you can push it to the class property right away.

```
<div class="box-regular" [ngClass]="[ { 'appear transparent' : getState1(firstIndex, secondIndex)}, { 'appear enlarge': getState3(firstIndex, secondIndex)} ]
```

The syntax for multiple values in ngclass is `[ngClass]= [ {}, {}]`,

where object {} contains class value and condition like this { 'classValue': condition },

If you need more than one class then use ternary operator but int this way:

```
[ngClass]=[ condition ? true : false, condition2 ? true: false, etc]
```

Comment: Ah, you got me on the right track at least. According to https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/how-to-add-a-class-based-on-condition-in-angular/ the proposed way to do it was: `<div [ngClass]="{'message': info.priority < 10,
                 'warn': info.priority > 10 && info.priority < 20, 
                 'error fa fa-exclamation-triangle': info.priority>30}">`

Comment: Exactly, great.

Answer (score 0):

If we reformulate the question from "how do do it with ngClass" into "how to do it in Angular", the answer would be - use `[class.your-class]="condition"` syntax.
The docs specifically highlight this as a preferred method, even mentioning that ngClass is gonna be deprecated in future.

Docs: https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding#class-binding